# Downgrade qt in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, qt

I use Ubuntu 13.04. Does anybody know how to downgrade qt to the version 4.8.2?

Comment: Try [installing the Qt 4.8.4 libraries?](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the newest version by

```
 sudo apt-get purge qt5-default
```

and it should work. when you need qt5 again you can simply install it again.